# I get an error "No such module 'FirebaseFirestore'"

Tags: firebase

I imported a new Firebase database into my Xcode project for an iOS app, and in the "UserData" file, I had to import FirebaseFirestore at the top of the file, but I get a "No such module 'FirebaseFirestore'" error. I have no idea how to install such a module, I am very new to this. Any information will be very helpful.

If you need me to provide more information on anything, please let me know what and I will.

Xcode version: 14.2
I added Firebase via Swift Package Manager
Analytics is also being used (Firebase product)
App is iOS only

I don't know what to do, but I want the database to work, so that everytime a person registers on the app, their details are saved in the database and are accessible by everyone who has the app installed on their device.

Comment: do you have a solution?